# Spritesheet animation with scaled frames

Tags: c++, animation, cocos2d-x, scale, cocos2d-x-3.0

In order to create an animation in cocos2d-x 3.2 I do this:

```
 SpriteFrameCache* cache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();

    Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames(15);

    for(int i = 1; i <= 7; ++i)
    {
        SpriteFrame* frame = cache->getSpriteFrameByName(String::createWithFormat("%d.png", i)->getCString());
        animFrames.pushBack(frame);
    }


    auto animation = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, 1 / animFrames.size());
    auto animate = Animate::create(animation);
    pSprite->runAction(animate);
```

But now I need some frames to scaleByX with -1 in order to create a mirrored image. `SpriteFrame` has not `scale` method. Also I can't `scale` the `pSprite` as only some of the frames should be scaled. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Scaled dynamically, or you'd like to create a new Animation entirely?

Comment: New animation is OK!

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty weird situation :)

1. You can schedule an update selector on sprite and set flipX to true/false based on your desired conditions. **That's my personal preference.**
2. You can't hack SpriteFrame that way, but you can use RenderTexture: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/d9/ddc/classcocos2d_1_1_render_texture.html - flip your desired sprites in a new texture, basically generate a new sprite-sheet on the fly. **Now that's a bad idea.**

Comment: I have got a feedback that in this case I shoul use Skeletal animations. What you think @Vorren?